# How to Convert updated_at to Conventional 12 Hour Format with My Time Zone?

Tags: datetime, timezone, elixir, ecto, datetime-conversion

In Phoenix, Ecto gives me a timestamp named **updated_at**, and it presents time in this way:

```
2023-05-31T18:44:44
```

I want to format it to 12 hour time and convert it to *my* time zone.

I can format it to a 12-hour time style while not affecting the time zone by doing this:

```
Calendar.strftime(updated_at,"%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This gives me a format that looks like this:

```
31-05-23 06:59:01 PM
```

This is what I want, but the time zone is still incorrect.

I don't need to store the time with my time zone to the database, I just need to render the preexisting time data to the GUI formatted the way I described.

I could parse the string, turn the relevant parts into integers, do the math and re-stringify it, but I figure there might be a simpler answer.

My time zone is 5 hours less than the time recorded to the database.

Comment: `31-05-23` feels quite unconventional to me. The hyphen usually implies YMD order used by ISO8601.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of a string, it would be better to store the datetime in your database as a datetime, and configure ecto to return it as a `DateTime` by using [`timestamps(type: :utc_datetime_usec`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1)) (or [`:utc_datetime`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-primitive-types)) in your schema.

However, assuming you just have the string `2023-05-31T18:44:44`, you can do this:

1. Convert your string to a `NaiveDateTime` using [`NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#from_iso8601!/2)
2. Convert the `NaiveDateTime` to a `DateTime`, specifying the time zone the data is stored in using [`DateTime.from_naive/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_naive/3)
3. Convert the `DateTime` to your time zone using [`DateTime.shift_zone/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#shift_zone!/3)
4. Format the `DateTime` as you are already doing with [`Calendar.strftime/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Calendar.html#strftime/3)

You need to have [installed and configured a time zone database](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#module-time-zone-database).

Example, assuming `Europe/London` and `America/New_York` time zones (note the result can vary, but it works out to 5 hours for this date):

```elixir
"2023-05-31T18:44:44"
|> NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601!()
|> DateTime.from_naive!("Europe/London")
|> DateTime.shift_zone!("America/New_York")
|> Calendar.strftime("%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Result:

```elixir
"31-05-23 01:44:44 PM"
```

---

If you have configured Ecto to give you `DateTime`s in UTC, you can skip the first two steps (but New York is actually 4 hours behind UTC at that date, so the result will differ).

Comment: I omitted the timezone database and |> NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601!()  and it worked

Comment: What does `Calendar.get_time_zone_database()` return?

Comment: It looks like I had a a time zone database already installed from the experimenting I had done previous to the query.    "Tzdata.TimeZoneDatabase

Comment: Right, and it sounds like you already have a NaiveDateTime (not a string), which is why you didn't need `from_iso8601`. If you follow the advice in the first paragraph and update your schema, you won't need the `DateTime.from_naive!` call either.